# how can i know the location of my bitmap image saved?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-external-storage

i am trying to save a user's signatures in my app. its working well but i can't find where these images are saved in my external storage. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETEFR.png) is how my app looks

and below is the code

```
 public void saveSig(View view) {

    try {

        GestureOverlayView gestureView = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.signaturePad);

        gestureView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(gestureView.getDrawingCache());


        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "signature.png");

        f.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);

        os = new FileOutputStream(f);

        //compress to specified format (PNG), quality - which is ignored for PNG, and out stream

        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
        os.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),f.getAbsolutePath(),f.getName(),f.getName());

    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        Log.v("Gestures", e.getMessage());

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: it is stored on the root of your file system, SD card or internal storage.
open any file explorer app and you will find image there.

Comment: you can also get path using `f.getAbsolutePath()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api insertImage will insert an image and create a thumbnail in the system 
photo album,but because of the cache, in some mobilePhone we can not see the photo until we reboot the phone.

Here is a solution that is we can refresh the system photo album.

1.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

or(high efficiency)

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ picPath)));
```

2. ```
   final MediaScannerConnection msc = new MediaScannerConnection(mContext, new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {  

       public void onMediaScannerConnected() {  
          msc.scanFile("/sdcard/image.jpg", "image/jpeg");  
       }  

       public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {  
         msc.disconnect();  
       }  
   });
   ```

Comment: only rebooting the phone worked. thanks. you saved my day. but can you please tell how i can pass this file to a function as an argument ?